# PHP switch issue

Tags: php, api, switch-statement

I have output from API:

```
<?php foreach ($soccerseason->getFixturesByMatchday(1) as $fixture) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $fixture->homeTeamName; ?></td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td><?php echo $fixture->awayTeamName; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fixture->result->goalsHomeTeam; ?></td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td><?php echo $fixture->result->goalsAwayTeam; ?></td>
                </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

this works fine, it outputs names like: Walsall FC in:

```
<td><?php echo $fixture->homeTeamName; ?></td>
```

Now I want the output to be translated to FR language such "équipe rouge" instead of "Walsall FC"

I am trying this PHP Switch in the header of the php page, but I get blank screen:

```
switch ($teamName) {
    case $fixture->homeTeamName['Walsall FC']:
        echo "équipe rouge";
        break;
}
```

your help is appreciated.

Comment: You write you have output from "API". What API? Also, did you take your second snippet from a larger piece of code? If so, could you share that larger piece of code?

Comment: external API with json_decode, the second snippet is just a test!

Comment: Are snippet 1 and snippet 2 within the same PHP file? If so, could you show the entire PHP file? Otherwise, could you show *both* PHP files (at least the relevant parts)?

Comment: yes both snippets are in the same php page, the Switch is in the header and the TD is into the template, I could not paste the entire code here coz too large...

Comment: @Julian I have edited my question, please check it.

Comment: It looks good. :-) Don't forget to accept the answer if it works for you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put the variable inside the parentheses and the value after `case`:

```
switch ($fixture->homeTeamName) {
    case 'redBlackpool FC':
        echo "équipe rouge";
        break;
}
```

But maybe you are putting too much logic into the template? Perhaps you could do:

```
switch ($fixture->homeTeamName) {
    case 'redBlackpool FC':
        $translatedHomeTeamName =  "équipe rouge";
        break;
}
```

and then in the template:

```
<td><?php echo $translatedHomeTeamName; ?></td>
```

In case you can't modify the contents of the `<td>`, then you could do:

```
switch ($fixture->homeTeamName) {
    case 'redBlackpool FC':
        $fixture->homeTeamName =  "équipe rouge";
        break;
}
```

the above should be executed before the `<td>` is printed... Basically I'm just suggesting that you don't put the whole switch statement inside the `<td>` so you can keep your code tidy...

**Edit - based on edited question**

Since you are inside a `foreach` loop, then you need to translate the term inside the foreach, like so:

```
<?php foreach ($soccerseason->getFixturesByMatchday(1) as $fixture) { 

        switch ($fixture->homeTeamName) {
            case 'redBlackpool FC':
                $fixture->homeTeamName =  "équipe rouge";
                break;
            case 'blueBlackpool FC':
                $fixture->homeTeamName =  "équipe bleu";
                break;
            default:
            // here you can do something in case the team isn't any of the above.
        }
?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $fixture->homeTeamName; ?></td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td><?php echo $fixture->awayTeamName; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fixture->result->goalsHomeTeam; ?></td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><?php echo $fixture->result->goalsAwayTeam; ?></td>
            </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

**Update - example with function**
The function (you can put it in a separate file and then include it in the main script):

```
function translateTeam($homeTeamName)
    switch ($homeTeamName) {
        case 'redBlackpool FC':
            $homeTeamName =  "équipe rouge";
            break;
        case 'blueBlackpool FC':
            $homeTeamName =  "équipe bleu";
            break;
        default:
        // here you can do something in case the team isn't any of the above.
    }

    return $homeTeamName;
}
```

The `foreach` loop:

```
// Include the php script that contains translateTeam() here...

<?php foreach ($soccerseason->getFixturesByMatchday(1) as $fixture) { ?>
            <tr>
                // In the line below we call the function and pass the English name to it...
                <td><?php echo translateTeam($fixture->homeTeamName); ?></td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td><?php echo $fixture->awayTeamName; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fixture->result->goalsHomeTeam; ?></td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><?php echo $fixture->result->goalsAwayTeam; ?></td>
            </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: what about the output `<td><?php echo $fixture->homeTeamName; ?></td>`

Comment: First answer worked fine as stand alone: `switch ($fixture->homeTeamName) {
    case 'redBlackpool FC':
        echo "équipe rouge";
        break;
}$fixture->homeTeamName = "redBlackpool FC"; ` but no changes in TD with translatedHomeTeamName of second answer

Comment: I suppose that depends on the order of execution... as I said in another part of my answer, you would need to make sure that the variable (in this case `$translatedHomeTeamName`) gets the string assigned to it before it's printed... I don't know your code but you could easily investigate using a debugger...

Comment: they are in the same page, the php switch is in the page header, and the TD is down in the HTML template.

Comment: I have edited my question, maybe it is more clear now, I will not forget to accept the answer ;)

Comment: OK I saw it, have a look at the last edit at the end of the answer, I think this would work in your case...

Comment: If you are not doing anything in the `default` block (see comment in the code) then you can get rid of the line that says `default:`, it was just an example for you.

Comment: it worked ;) can I include the **switch** as external php or it must be hard coded in that place?

Comment: Since you are in a foreach loop, $fixture->homeTeamName is going to change at every iteration of the loop. So you could create a function that takes the $fixture->homeTeamName as an argument and returns the correct string... See latest update at the bottom

Comment: I tried but did not worked, I posted this issue as new question please check it :) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38727571/php-include-external-swich)

Comment: Regarding the other question I se it has been answered, my advice is try to always have all your include/require statements at the very beginning of your script, this way the code will be more maintainable.